# Share wifi for google nexus

Tags: 13.04, wireless

How I can share wifi from my laptop for using it on Google Nexus 7? I try do it with WEP-40/128 and with WEP-128, It's work for my another laptop but not for Nexus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean share your laptop's internet on your Google Nexus 7? You'd have to have a wired connection on your laptop/desktop computer. Create an Ad-Hoc Wireless Network from your computer. WEP Security. Then manually enter the SSID and Password on your Nexus device.

Breakdown

1. Create Ad-Hoc Wrieless Network (set up SSID, WEP Key)
2. Take Nexus Device and manually connect to the network you just created

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: What steps did you take to reproduce this? Because that's how you setup what you're talking about.

Comment: 1) Open system settings 2) Open tab "Network" 3) Get Wirelles and click "Use a Hotspot.." Then I press on button "create" 4) Click on butotn "Options..." 5) Configure SSID and WEP key 6) Save and share. I see it from my phone, but not from Nexus

Comment: Hmm... On Nexus you can't enter it manually? I know you don't see it in the Nexus list, but you can't enter manually from Nexus, the same info as you created on your computer?

Comment: Also, I just found out that it may be the Nexus issue, not your issue. So that's all I'll say, I don't want to lead you in the wrong direction, but others have said it was a Nexus related issue.

Comment: I wasn't much help, sorry - but you're welcome.

Comment: Did you figure it out?